# How to get thinner ends of hair particles?

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to make the ends of the hairs I make thinner than the root of it, does anyone know how to do that? Cause at the moment it looks too straw like. Thanks.

Comment: You need to look at your settings for hair shape. Try .01 for the tip size. Keep root size default to illustrate the difference you will see. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/hair/shape.html

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can only do it using Cycles.

So, once you've changed your render engine, head over to the *Particle Properties* tab and tweak the values under the *Hair Shape* section until you get satisfied with the result.

[image: Single-strand particle system]

The first three inputs are pretty intuitive, just mess with them; the fourth one is simply a global scaling factor.